# Get Raw Barcode data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I want to release values from ImageAnalyzer.analyze as raw values and send it to another Activity. Its become not so simple as it seems, because I cant override function with return. I also cant make Toast or open another Activity inside function, because I can`t sand Context in it. Please, help.

```
 private class ImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
   private fun degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees: Int): Int = when (degrees) {
        0 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
        90 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90
        180 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180
        270 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270
        else -> throw Exception("Rotation must be 0, 90, 180, or 270.")
    }
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy?, degrees: Int){
        val mediaImage = imageProxy?.image
        val imageRotation = degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees)
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageRotation)
            val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS).build()
            val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
              val result=  detector.detectInImage(image) .addOnSuccessListener(){barcodes->
                  for (barcode in barcodes) {
                      val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                      val corners = barcode.cornerPoints
                      val rawValue = barcode.rawValue
                      val valueType = barcode.valueType
                      // See API reference for complete list of supported types
                      when (valueType) {
                          FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_WIFI -> {
                              val ssid = barcode.wifi!!.ssid
                              val password = barcode.wifi!!.password
                              val type = barcode.wifi!!.encryptionType
                          }
                          FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_URL -> {
                              val title = barcode.url!!.title
                              val url = barcode.url!!.url
                          }
                      }
                  }

              }
                    .addOnFailureListener() {}
           }
  }

}
```

I did next. If I try to make Toast with this context app is crashing. Try to open another activity, function startActivity() want some strange parameters. I don`t know what bundle it need

```
 private class ImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    val liveScan=LiveScan()
    val contex=liveScan.applicationContext


    private fun degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees: Int): Int = when (degrees) {
        0 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
        90 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90
        180 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180
        270 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270
        else -> throw Exception("Rotation must be 0, 90, 180, or 270.")
    }
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy?, degrees: Int){
        val mediaImage = imageProxy?.image
        val imageRotation = degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees)
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageRotation)
            val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS).build()
            val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
              val result=  detector.detectInImage(image)
                  .addOnSuccessListener(){ barcodes->
                  for (barcode in barcodes) {
                      val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                      val corners = barcode.cornerPoints
                      val rawValue = barcode.rawValue
                      val intent= Intent(contex,DataAnalyse::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                   startActivity(contex,intent,)

                  }
              }
                    .addOnFailureListener() {Log.d("CameraXApp", "no_barcode")}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't speak Kotlin but in Java `ImageAnalyzer` could have a `ImageAnalyzerClient` interface which another class would implement and provide itself to `ImageAnalyzer` as an instance of an `ImageAnalyzerClient`. The interface would have a method that receives data from `ImageAnalyzer`. Looks like here's a brief tutorial on doing that in Kotlin first in the "Java way" and then in a "Kotlin way": [https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-functions-an-alternative-to-interfaces-7cfb3c435900](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-functions-an-alternative-to-interfaces-7cfb3c435900).

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Even if it is method that receives data I have no idea where call it. Get data to string or array from addOnSuccesListener seems impossible. In examples I cant see how they extract data. It all so sad(((

Comment: I have only one idea: try use camerax in fragment. As I remember to return data from fragment to activity I need no context?

Comment: _"I have no idea where call it."_ You want to send `rawValue` from `ImageAnalyzer.analyze()`, so you call it in `ImageAnalyzer.analyze()` once `rawValue` has been set to a value. Except that you write _"send it to another Activity"_ and have experimented with an `Intent` to start another `Activity`, so I guess I'm not really sure about the exact use case anymore. Having `startActivity()` inside a for loop definitely looks like a bad idea. So, do you perhaps want to send a collection of `rawValue` objects? Is the `DataAnalyse` class even an `Activity`? You could edit the question and clarify.

Comment: I understand, what get raw value from loop as single parametr is not good idea. May be it's reason to crash. But show it in Toast must working. I cant get context in addOnSuccesListener at all. And it is worse, because Intent need context. Ok. I want extract data from barcode(s) as raw values and sand it to another activity

Answer (score 0):

It's my issue, that satisfy my needs. As least now.

```
package com.barcodescaner

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.view.Surface
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.ContentView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcode
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImageMetadata
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.security.AccessController.getContext
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import android.widget.Toast.makeText as makeText1
import android.widget.Toast.makeText as makeText2
import com.barcodescaner.Post


private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10

 const val FLAGS_FULLSCREEN =
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

 // This is an array of all the permission specified in the manifest.
private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA )


class LiveScan : AppCompatActivity() {
private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView
lateinit var value:String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_scan)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  window.decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(FLAGS_FULLSCREEN)
        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder)
        viewFinder.post() { startCamera() }
        viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            updateTransform()
        }
    }


    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
       // val strin


    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
        )
    }
 }



override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            finish()
        }
    }
}

private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        baseContext, it
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
fun startCamera() {
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetResolution(Size(640, 480))
    }.build()

    val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {

        val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeView(viewFinder)
        parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

        viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
        updateTransform()
    }

    val imageAnalysisConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        .build()




    val qrCodeAnalyzer = QrCodeAnalyzer { qrCodes ->

if (qrCodes.isNotEmpty()) {

value= qrCodes[0].toString()
val intent=Intent(baseContext,DataAnalyse::class.java)
intent.putExtra("BarcodeValue",value)
startActivity(intent)
CameraX.unbindAll()
}}

    val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis(imageAnalysisConfig).apply {       setAnalyzer(executor,qrCodeAnalyzer)  }



    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageAnalyzer)


}

private fun valuesSander(list:List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>){
val intent = Intent(baseContext,DataAnalyse::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun updateTransform() {
    // TODO: Implement camera viewfinder transformations
    val matrix = Matrix()
    val centerX = viewFinder.width / 2f
    val centerY = viewFinder.height / 2f
    val rotationDegrees = when (viewFinder.display.rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> 0
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> 90
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
        else -> return
    }
    matrix.postRotate(-rotationDegrees.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)
    viewFinder.setTransform(matrix)
}
}





class QrCodeAnalyzer(
private val onQrCodesDetected: (qrCode: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>) -> Unit
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
        // We want to only detect QR codes.
        .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
        .build()

    val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)

    val rotation = rotationDegreesToFirebaseRotation(rotationDegrees)
    val visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(image.image!!, rotation)
    detector.detectInImage(visionImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
            onQrCodesDetected(barcodes)

        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("QrCodeAnalyzer", "something went wrong", it)

        }.addOnCompleteListener{

        }
}
private fun rotationDegreesToFirebaseRotation(rotationDegrees: Int): Int {
    return when (rotationDegrees) {
        0 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
        90 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90
        180 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180
        270 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not supported")
    }
}
}
```